# BigQuery - Data Transfer Jobs

Tags: google-bigquery, data-transfer

I'm getting this error while defining a [Data Transfer Job via UI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transfer-service-overview):

> Error in updating a transfer: Invalid schedule [every 2 hours].
>   Schedule has to be consistent with CustomScheduleGranularity [daily:
>   true ]

How can I run a job more than once a day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the docs at the link below, you are limited to the frequency schedules of the individual sources:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transfer-service-overview

For example, Google AdWords states the schedule as `Daily, at the time the Transfer is first created (default)`, so you cannot load intra day data.